# OR operator for checking branches in Octopus Deploy

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I have a 'Deploy a nuget package' step in Octopus. In that step, I want to deploy a nuget package and have some deployment script executed.

Now I want the deployment to happen only for master and hotfix branches.SO I added a condition like this in the deployemnt script:

```
 if ($BranchName.ToLower().equals("master") -or $BranchName.ToLower().contains("hotfix")) 
 {
  ...................
 }
```

But it doesn't work and I am gettin error like this

```
 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.'
```

How can I achieve this?

Note: I don't have any pre-deployment and post-deployment script

Comment: Your code works fine as long as `$branchname` contains data and is a string. The error is pretty clear so far. `$branchname` appears to be null. how do you populate it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to check if $BranchName is null? You can also compare strings with inbuilt operators:

```
if ($BranchName -and ($BranchName -ilike "master" -or $BranchName -ilike "*hotfix*"))
 {
  ...................
 }
```

Comment: Those operators are case insensitive by default